# React Redux - Check if ID exists in state at Reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to prevent duplicate messages from being pushed into the state. Below is my messagesReducer.

```
const initialState = List([]);

const messagesReducer = {
 [actionTypes.ADD_NEW_RESPONSE_MESSAGE]: (state, { text }) => state.push(createNewMessage(text, MESSAGE_SENDER.RESPONSE)),

}

export default (state = initialState, action) => createReducer(messsagesReducer, state, action);
```

Comment: Thank you both @carrany and @ali-nasserzadeh for your answers.

For both answers I am getting the error below:


```Error: Given action "MESSAGES/ADD_NEW_RESPONSE_MESSAGE", reducer "messages" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state.```


The messagesReducer should create an array called messages in state. To avoid duplicates I want to check if the id in the text object below does not exist in messages then call createNewMessage(text, MESSAGE_SENDER.RESPONSE).


```text { id: '1', title: 'Hello world' }```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the array for duplicates using the higher order function 'some'. Also currently your reducer returns the length of the array, because that is how .push works, which is probably not what you want.

In the code below I assume that the id of the message is saved in the attribute 'id' inside the message object.

```
const initialState = [];

const messagesReducer = {
 [actionTypes.ADD_NEW_RESPONSE_MESSAGE]: (state, { text }) => { 
     if (!state.some(m => m.id === MESSAGE_SENDER.RESPONSE)) return [...state, (createNewMessage(text, MESSAGE_SENDER.RESPONSE))];
     return state;
 },
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => createReducer(messsagesReducer, state, action);
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering you are working with a list and you want to check if Id exists before pushing,
i would the following approach:

```
//Returns a True or False depending on if it finds the item or not
    let find_status = !!state.find(item => item.id === message.id)

   find_status?state.push(message):state;
```